# Rotate links and vertically centre on page with fixed positioning

Tags: css

Ive rotated some links in a list. Now I need them to be vertically centered on the page and have a fixed position.

This is what I want: 
[image]

Below is my attempt but im getting stuck. If the links are centered within the ul, before its rotated the ul has a width of 100%. However once rotated its height is its width before it was centered, which is not 100% of the page.

I could use javascript to find the window height and apply the value with CSS to the ul's width, but im wondering if there is a CSS only solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/X3Nf9/5/

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

li, a {
      display: inline-block;
}
ul {
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;

     -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    transform: rotate(-90deg); 

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/X3Nf9/8/

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:50vw;
}
```

You might want to check for browser compatibility, some older browsers may not like the vw unit.  Since you are using transforms, you are already limited yourself to newer browsers, but I'm not sure there is an exact overlap of which support the vw unit.